# Wagtail: PageChooserPanel not showing up

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to add a PageChooserPanel to a Related Links model, and it is not showing up in the admin. I get no errors in migrating or loading the page. Here is the code:

sua_base/models.py:

```
class RelatedLinks(models.Model):

    page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField("Embed URL", blank=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        PageChooserPanel('page'),
        FieldPanel('url'),
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        verbose_name = "Related Link"
        verbose_name_plural = "Related Links"
```

app/models.py:

```
from sua_base.models import WebPage, Section, RelatedLinks

class SUAWebPage(WebPage):

        sidebar_content_panels = [
            InlinePanel('related_links', label="Related Links")
        ]

        edit_handler = TabbedInterface([
            ObjectList(content_panels, heading='Content'),
            ObjectList(sidebar_content_panels, heading='Sidebar'),
            ObjectList(WebPage.settings_panels, heading='Settings', classname="settings"),
            ObjectList(Page.promote_panels, heading='Promote'),
        ])

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "SUA Web Page"
            verbose_name_plural = "SUA Web Pages"


    class SUAWebPageRelatedLinks(RelatedLinks, Orderable):
        page = ParentalKey(SUAWebPage, related_name='related_links')
```

The other 2 fields (`title` and `url`) show up fine, it's just the PageChooserPanel that has disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is failing because you're using the name `page` for both the `ForeignKey` to the page you're linking to (in `RelatedLinks`), and the `ParentalKey` pointing back to the containing page (in `SUAWebPageRelatedLinks`). You'll need to rename one of them.

Comment: Sigh, I knew it was something dumb. Thank you!